# AWS DNS Validation on GoDaddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, dns, masking

I'm trying to secure my domain.com website. I've bought a GoDaddy domain and hosting for two years holding up a static page up there.

I want it to be secure to redirect it to my EC2 instance, where the application is hosted. I found that AWS provides free SSL certs for my instances.

What I'm trying to do is to set up a certificate on AWS by DNS validation and add it on GoDaddy but I'm really confused about redirections, A hosts, CNET hosts and all that. They give me a (CNAME, Name, Value) to add on GoDaddy but I can't make it work.

Is this the way to work? Should I only SSL protect the instance? Can I redirect my domain.com to my instance under https?

I'd like some help with setting that up and some guidance on what do I have to research, if DNS functioning or networking or what. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Easiest way is, have R53 resource records setup and let GoDaddy handover the DNS resolution to AWS R53. This might help: https://www.cloudassessments.com/blog/configure-dns-with-route-53/

Comment: This is great. It clarifies how does DNS get resolved. But after that, how do I set up SSL? How do I secure my godaddy domain with aws certificate.

Comment: Wait.. After those steps I have routing defined in Route 53. Then the SSL validation will be made through that way, easier. I'll check that out.

Comment: Yes, now everything on AWS. Try it. Good luck!

Comment: that link is 404 now. would you have another link. I am trying to achieve this also

Answer (score 3):

For validate a domain name like example.com you have to write just the first part of xxx1.example.com. without your domain name and without suffix dot. Like this:

```
TYPE: CNAME
NAME: xxx1
VALUE: xxx2.acm-validation.aws
```

For validate www.example.com you have to write just the first part of xxx3.www.example.com. without the domain name and without suffix dot, but including www. Like this:

```
TYPE: CNAME
NAME: xxx3.www
VALUE: xxx4.acm-validation.aws
```

You can test above configuration after some minutes with:

```
dig TXT +short +noshort xxx1.example.com

dig TXT +short +noshort xxx2.www.example.com
```